# Set default locale for bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, deploy, static-content-deploy

When running deploy static content on my store i always need to add the locale at the end of the command or my store breaks.

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

I was wondering if I am doing anything wrong here and if i can set this so the locale is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't answer OP's question:

> I was wondering if I am doing anything wrong here and if I can set this so the locale is not required

There is a way to ensure only used locales are deployed.
You can employ [GetPageSpeed n98-magerun2 commands](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/n98-magerun2-module-getpagespeed) for the job, e.g.:

```
php ./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy $(n98-magerun2 deploy:locale:active)
```

You can save it to a script which is part of your deployment workflow, and then no matter what actual locales are used, only they will be "deployed", without having to hardcode them anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

Magento2 deploys only for en_US locale by default.
And if you are using en_GB locale for your site then you need to always add the locale to ythe deploy command.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Answer (score 1):

You need deploy your language to run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like that.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language en_GB
```

for reference please check [Magento deploy command](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Comment: Please check it and let me know it is working fine.